# Установщик Python не начинает установку, что делать?

Tags: python

Такая проблема с установкой Python 3.8.3, установщик не хочет ничего скачивать, останавливается на initializing... дальше всё, ничего не происходит, что делать в таком случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у Вас Windows, попробуйте вместо Windows web-based installer, например, Windows x86 executable installer отсюда:

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

В последнем случае скачивается уже готовый дистрибутив для установки.